# SQL: Calculate Percentage in new column using another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found it hard to describe what I wanted to do in the title, but I will be more specific here.
I have a reasonably long query:

```
 SELECT 

    /*Amount earned with validation to remove outlying figures*/

    Case When SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])>=0.01 OR SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])<0 Then SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue]) ELSE 0 END AS 'Amount', 

    /*Profit earned (is already calculated then input into db, this just pulls that figure*/

    SUM(t2.[Profit]) AS 'Profit', 

    /*Product Type - pulls the product type so that we can sort by product*/

    t1.[ucIIProductType] AS 'Product Type', 

    /*Profit Percentage - This is to calculate the percentage of profit based on the sales price which uses 2 different columns - Case ensures that there are no wild values appearing in the reports as previously experienced*/

    Case When SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])>=0.01 OR SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])<0 THEN (SUM(t2.[Profit])/SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])) ELSE 0 END AS 'Profit Percentage',

/*Percentage of Turnover*/
    *SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])/(Select SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue]) OVER() FROM [_bvSTTransactionsFull]) AS 'PoT'

    /*The join is connect the product type with the profit and the amount*/

    FROM  [dbo].[StkItem] AS t1
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[_bvSTTransactionsFull] AS t2

    /*There attirbutes are the links between the tables*/
    ON t1.[StockLink]=t2.[AccountLink]

    WHERE t2.[TxDate] BETWEEN '1/Aug/2014' AND '31/Aug/2014' AND ISNUMERIC(t2.[Account]) = 1

    Group By t1.[ucIIProductType]
```

The 'Percentage of Turnover' part I am having trouble with - I am trying to calculate the percentage of the Amount based on the total amount - using the same column. So eg: I want to take the Amount value in row 1, then divide it by the total amount of the entire column and then have that value listed in a new column.  But I keep getting errors or I Keep getting 1 (because it wants to divide the value by the same value. CAN anyone please advise me on proper syntax for solving this:

```
/*Percentage of Turnover*/
        *SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])/(Select SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue]) OVER() FROM [_bvSTTransactionsFull]) AS 'PoT'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want one of the following:

```
SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])/(Select SUM(t.[ActualSalesValue]) FROM [_bvSTTransactionsFull] t) AS PoT
```

or:

```
SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])/(SUM(SUM(t2.[ActualSalesValue])) OVER() ) AS PoT
```

Note:  you should use single quotes only for string and date constants, not for column and table names.  If you need to escape names, use square braces.

Comment: For the First answer, I get the following Error:

"Subquery returned more than 1 value.  This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=,<,<=,>,>= or when the subquery is used as an expression"

For the second answer i get the following error:
"Column 'dbo._bvSTTransactionFull.ActualSalesValue' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: The first error perplexes me.  The subquery *does* return only one value.  I fixed the second problem.

Comment: The second one now computes, but it is pulling an odd figure.

<br>

example: Amount = 88832.48, Total Amount = 3958523.68, New Column Value should be = 0.0224

<br>

However, it is currently producing the value: 2.244

Why is it doing this?

Comment: @Tal . . . I see the problem with the first version.  The inner query had no alias.  I imagine the second fails because amounts are being multiplied by the joins somehow.

Comment: @Gordon...Unfortunately it still pulls the same error (note I removed an errant '\' that was included in your edit.  But still no luck with it.

Comment: @Tal . . . That `t2\.` should have been `t.`.

Comment: Ever with remove of the '\' it still did not function. Produced the same error...